# MySQL query with fallbacks (COALESCE) and JOINS

Tags: php, mysql

So I am having a hard time trying to write a single query for this. I have a table we will call table_a. I need to pull a single record that matches certain criteria. If the first one produces nothing then fall back to another one. I have been at this awhile and it very well could be something simple I am just missing.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(ta.id,tb.id,0) AS theid,
FROM table_a
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT table_a.id
    FROM table_a
    WHERE table_a.field_3='1' AND table_a.field_4='100' AND table_a.user_id='someidhere'
) AS ta
ON table_a.id = ta.id

RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT table_a.id
    FROM table_a
    WHERE table_a.field_5='2' AND table_a.field_4='100' AND table_a.user_id='someidhere'
) AS tb
ON table_a.id = tb.id
```

The problem with RIGHT JOIN is if the first one does not produce a record it will not go on to the next one, if I do LEFT JOIN it will pull all the records from table_a, if I specify WHERE table_a.user_id='someidhere' it will obviously pull all the records for that user. I am only looking for one. Essentially only field_3 and field_5 will be the ones that change. If I can not find something for field_3 it moves onto field_5. This will run on a table with 80k records. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a newbie, starting out with a cryptic example is not the greatest, but I'm trying here.  Your query in itself is rather pointless on what it is doing.  Its joining to itself to ultimately grab the ID of a thing that is for a certain user ID and field 4 value, but the field 3 or 5 should be a 1 or 2 respectively.

So, I've written the query directly to the "a" table for the user ID and field 4 which were common regardless of your right-join... THEN added an ( OR ) for your field 3 and 5 columns.  This way, I only care about those of the 3 OR 5 value with same user/field 4 area.  The ORDER BY clause will force that any record with the field 3 value of 1 is sorted first, then any that are field 5 = 2 will be secondary... So the final first record would be the '1' entry if one existed.

```
SELECT
      table_a.id
   FROM 
      table_a
   where 
          table_a.user_id = 'someidhere'
      AND table_a.field_4 = '100'
      AND (   table_a.field_3 = '1'
           OR table_a.field_5 = '2' )
   order by
      case when table_a.field_3 = '1' 
           then 1 else 2 end
```

So, if there are multiple records returned, you only need to care about the first one returned (in case there are two that qualify).

Comment: Didn't mean to be cryptic. Thanks works great. I guess I was trying to overkill it ;)